# Computing Mathematical functions over multiple runs (Numpy)

Tags: python, file-io, numpy, matplotlib

I'm currently running a series of experiments, which I need to run multiple times to generate decent error bars.
Each experiment outputs a file which has various info like mean/std/throughput/latency/nth percentile etc.

I then plot each of these values, but to get a more sensible result, I need to take the mean of all of these files for each cell, and plot that with the standard deviation obtained as error bars.

The code I have so far does not however work:

```
 data_1 = np.loadtxt(fold + "/" +  "clients_1.txt")
 data_2 = np.loadtxt(fold + "/" +  "clients_2.txt")
 data_3 = np.loadtxt(fold + "/" +  "clients_3.txt")
 data = [data_1,data_2,data_3]
 d_avg = sum(data) / float(len(data))
 err   = np.std(d_avg)
 plt.plot(d_avg[:,19],d_avg[:,7], label='Test Plot', yerr = err[:,7] )
```

The error I get is this:

```
IndexError: 0-d arrays can only use a single () or a list of newaxes (and a single ...) as an index
```

Slightly confused as to what the issue is. The `d_agv` file prints ok.

All the client files have the same number of column rows, and each cell in one file corresponds to the same cell in the other file (potentially with different values obviously)

The format of each row in each file is :

```
1 1 50 1 1 0 100 11.30000 9.00000 50.00000 32.09000 5.66480 9.00000 9.00000 10.00000 11.00000 12.00000 13.55000 32.85000 39.47368
```

and there are multiple such rows.

Comment: You cannot use numpy function on list, you have to convert your data to numpy arrays. Can you give more information about `clients_n.txt` files? Give a few lines from them? Are they all contain the same number of elements?

Comment: Minor detail, you can (should?) use `os.path.join()` for your filenames instead of string concatenation.

Comment: @Victor edited to reflect this

Comment: OK now it's a little bit clearer, but I still don't understand what you intend to do with the data? You want to find an average and standard deviation for _every_ column in _every_ table, and then plot what?

Comment: Each file represents a run of the same experiment. The plots I generate is then the average of the values across these files (if you look on the left 1 1 50 are number of clients/machines etc, floats are the values ofbtained) with the standard deviation across these files.

Comment: Check what `err` is, not what `d_avg` is...

Comment: See docs ( http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html ) `np.std` returns the std of the flattened array, as does `sum`.  You need to explicitly tell numpy which axis to operate along

Comment: @ViktorKerkez many numpy functions will auto-convert lists to arrays under the hood `np.mean(range(72))` works just fine.

Comment: @tcaswell Yes, but if his arrays are not the same shape it wont work: `np.std([np.random.randn(3,3), np.random.randn(4, 5)])`, which is what I first assumed since he didn't gave any other description of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so if I understood you well, you want the mean and the standard deviation across the runs of the experiment. If, for example, we had 2 runs with some random data given in tables down, the mean would be:

```
run 1   run 2       mean

1 2 3   1 3 2    1  2.5 2.5
4 5 6   5 4 6   4.5 4.5  6
7 8 9   7 8 9    7   8   9
```

If my assumption is correct, this is the code you want:

```
data_1 = np.loadtxt(fold + "/" +  "clients_1.txt")
data_2 = np.loadtxt(fold + "/" +  "clients_2.txt")
data_3 = np.loadtxt(fold + "/" +  "clients_3.txt")

data = np.array([data_1, data_2, data_3])
data_avg = data.mean(axis=0)
data_err = data.std(axis=0)
plt.plot(data_avg[:,19], data_avg[:,7], label='Test Plot')
```